# Excel formula to compare two columns

Tags: java, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, compare

I need a formula to compare two columns which will return true if all integer values in first column are not less then all integer values in second column.

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE:**

I need to do some calculations if numbers in each row in column H greater then value in column I (picture below). I need this formula to return TRUE or FALSE because I will use it in another more complex formula.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvYjD.png)

**UPDATE:**

I form this excel file from Java code and I need include this formula to the cell. It's not good to use any extra columns in this case.

Comment: any example of what you have tried or how it should look would help. This would leave many guessing, not what SO is about imo.

Comment: @krib added some information to the question.

Comment: @pnuts any amount, sorry for bad example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array formula

```
{=AND(H6:H32>I6:I32)}
```

will give you `TRUE` if each value in column `H` is greater than the corresponding value in `I` (so `H6` greater than `I6` and `H7` greater than `I7` and ... and `H32` greater than `I32`) and `FALSE` otherwise.

Array formulae are entered through Excel's GUI using CTL + SHIFT + ENTER keyboard combination to commit the formula or by setting a cell's `FormulaArray` property in VBA.

Alternatively, this non-array formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(H6:H32>I6:I32))=27
```

will also deliver the same result but in a less elegant way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it work for me. We use Apache POI to generate excel document, and there is method Sheet.setArrayFormula(String formula, CellRangeAddress range).

Comment: Your original question  was not very clear about precisely what you were seeking to achieve. It was the combination of your example (where all the values in column H were greater than those in column I) and your comment about using  IF(H6:H32 >= I6:I32; TRUE; FALSE) in response to another answer that lead to the insight into your real requirement.

Answer (score 1):

i would do it in this way:
result of each line (here C2): `=IF(A2>=B2;1;0)`
and then the end result (here C5): `=IF(COUNTIF(C2:C4;0)>0;TRUE;FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it won't be good if I use extra column, because I form this excel from Java code.

Comment: ah ok, so i think you have to concat all rows (maybe in java) in one formula: `=IF(AND(A2>=B2;A3>=B3;A4>=B4);TRUE;FALSE)`

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use range of cell? Something like IF(H6:H32 >= I6:I32; TRUE; FALSE).

Comment: i don't think so. but why u can't use an extra column? obviously that would be the easiest way to do that.

Comment: I can use, but  I hope that better solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have column A and B, then try this in column C:

```
=(B1<=A1)
```

It will return as True or False in column C

Comment: I have several rows in my columns.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: In the image you provided seems to show it as a single numeral per cell. I would just use =(I5<=H5) in column J, assuming that 5 is the row you want to start from, then drag the cell down to copy the formulas

Comment: My example would return True or False, but I didn't get what you were asking for when you said "... and then just use it inside IF and do calculations which I need"

Comment: I form this excel from Java code, that is why i need one formula. And i need to include this formula to excel, not just provide the result.

Comment: I'd include that in the question as well. Though I'm not quite understanding what part of my solution is not working for your need?

Comment: Updated, sorry for bad question (actually, this is my first one). Your solution use extra column, and I need just formula in one cell.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding. You already have 2 columns. Where do you want this formula to populate?

Comment: I need another one cell, which will contains formula. And if formula from question will return true, it should calculate some bonus.

Comment: Keeping it simple, this would work: =IF(I5<=H5,1+2) ... In place of 1+2, you can put any formula you want.

Comment: Yes, but I have several rows and I need to compare all of them

Comment: I'm not sure how you would compare multiple rows into one cell, that's not really how excel works

Comment: I think, that I have to use extra column, if there isn't better solution.